# Weird behaviour with bash script for file arguments

Tags: bash

So I built a super simple script to allow me to search across all directories relative to the one the script is run from that will find the first argument and replace it with the second one:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash -f
word_to_look_for=$1
substitue=$2

find ./ type f -exec sed -i "" "s/$word_to_look_for/$substitute/g" {} \;
echo "Replaced ($word_to_look_for) with ($substitue)"
```

For some reason though, this bit -> `"s/$word_to_look_for/$substitute/g"`

would only output as `s/wordImlookingfor//g` and as result sed would replace it with empty text, to get this to work as intended I had change the script to the following:

```
sed_arg="s/$word_to_look_for"
sed_arg="$sed_arg/$substitue/g"

find ./ type f -exec sed -i "" "$sed_arg" {} \;
echo "Replaced ($word_to_look_for) with ($substitue)"
```

I'm just wondering, why did bash not seem to like the way I had it in the first version?

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled `substitute` as `substitue` everywhere except for one place:

```
"s/$word_to_look_for/$substitute/g"
```

So bash expanded the variable `$substitute`, which was never set, while the other variable (`$substitue`) was set but never used.